# .equals() method ,comparing the two objects of a class not giving exact results

Tags: java

I have a class named student contains two variables name,no and i have created two objects for the class, now i want to check whether both objects are same or not. I am using .equals() method but i am not getting proper output.

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int no;

    Student(String name,int no){
        this.name=name;
        this.no=no;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("abc", 10);
        Student s2 = new Student("abc", 10);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    }
}
```

output: false

Comment: You need to override 'equals()' in Student class, by default it is Object class whic compares object references

Comment: You need override equals method with `name` and `no`.

Comment: Here the way you can override equals method @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj){
  if(obj == null){
   return false;
  }
  final Student student = (Student) obj;
  if(student.name.equals(this.name) && student.no == this.no){
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided an implementation of `equals`, meaning it will use the default one it inherits from `Object`, which is the same as: `s1 == s2`, which returns false because they are not the same object.

You'll need to provide your own implementation.

Take a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/).

Comment: apparently this triggers a downvote. Might I ask why?